# How to convert xml to non-xml text using XQuery in SQL Server 2005/2008?

Tags: sql-server, xml, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, xquery

The following code will return `select $f/field/text() from table1`

```
declare @x xml = '<meta><field>Column1</field></meta>';
select @x.query('
for $f in /meta
return
    "select $f/field/text() from table1"
')
```

I tried to change the return part to `"select"+$f/field` or `"select" $f/field` and these cannot be parsed.

---

**Update:**
 The `@x` will be generated from a table with `for xml raw,elements`. The purpose to use xml/xquery is to avoid the boilerplate string concatenations. It seems XQuery cannot transform xml to text?

---

**Updated question:**
The following is the code I want to write.

```
declare @meta table (field sysname primary key, validate varchar(8000));
insert into @meta values ('Col1', '< 100'), ('Col2', '> Col1');

declare @x xml = (select * from @meta for xml path('meta'));
select @x;

-- The following code cannot be parsed. It will be nice to replace /meta/field/text() with shorter variable too
select @x.query('
    "select 1" 
        {"," /meta/field/text() "= case when" /meta/field/text() /meta/validate/text() "then" /meta/field/text()}
    "from table1"
    "where 1=1 " 
        { "or (" /meta/field/text() /meta/validate/text() ")" }
')
```

And the generated result should be,

```
select 1
    , Col1 = case when Col1 < 100 then Col1 end
    , Col2 = case when Col2 > Col1 then Col2 end
from table1
where 1=1
        or (Col1 < 100)
        or (Col2 > Col1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just need to wrap everything in an outer xml tag.

Answer (score 2):

Use [.value](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178030.aspx) instead of [.query](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191474.aspx) to get a value from XML.

```
declare @x xml = '<meta><field>Column1</field></meta>';

select 'select '+quotename(@x.value('(/meta/field)[1]', 'sysname'))+' from table1'
```

Result:

```
select [Column1] from table1
```

**Update:**

Here is a way to build your query using the meta table directly.

```
select 'select '+
       stuff((select ', '+field+' = case when '+field+' '+validate+' then '+field+' end'
              from @meta 
              for xml path(''), type).value('.', 'nvarchar(max)'), 1, 2, '')+
       ' from table1 where '+
       stuff((select ' or ('+field+' '+validate+')'
              from @meta 
              for xml path(''), type).value('.', 'nvarchar(max)'), 1, 4, '')
```

Result:

```
select Col1 = case when Col1 < 100 then Col1 end,
       Col2 = case when Col2 > Col1 then Col2 end 
from table1 
where (Col1 < 100) or 
      (Col2 > Col1)
```

Comment: Thanks. The @x will be generated from a table with `for xml raw,elements`. The purpose to use xml/xquery is to avoid the boilerplate string concatenations. It seems XQuery cannot transform xml to text?

Comment: @NickW - XQuery is quite capable. If you could update your question with a bit more of what you are trying to do I might have some ideas that could be helpful to you. Getting some text out of XML is usually no problem but I don't understand the issues you have by reading your question.

Comment: @NickW - update your question with the table you are using, some sample data and expected output and perhaps some limitations like "please no cursors or loops" :)

Comment: @NickW - Updated answer with a version using the meta table instead of the XML. Please let me know if you for some reason really need to use the XML instead.

Comment: I've been using the string concatenation and want to find a more elegant approach for these kind of tasks. It's harder to maintain the code and the extra stuffing/trimming make it code looking messier. Unfortunately there is not an easy way to do xslt in T-Sql.

Answer (score 1):

The solution:

```
--drop table #tmp
declare @x xml = '<meta><field>Column1</field> <field>Column2</field></meta>';
declare @field  varchar(max) 
CREATE TABLE #tmp (field varchar(max) )

set @field = ( select cast(@x.query('for $f in /meta/field
return  concat("insert into #tmp(field)  select ", $f, " from table1;")
') as varchar(max)))

 EXEC (@field);

 select field from #tmp

 drop table #tmp
```

Comment: $f will be surrounded with <field>.